# Send SMS with out saving it in sent item in kitkat

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, smsmanager

I am developing an application which needs to send SMS.

I am using SmsManager.SendTextMessage and SmsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage , Both of them are working well , the main problem is sent message will be saved on sent items(only in Kitkat , the older version don't save SMS) , but I don't need to save message.

My app is default messageing app.
What should I do to prevent saving SMS in kitkat?

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    String body ="Test";
    String to = "5556";
    ArrayList<String> parts =smsManager.divideMessage(body);

    smsManager.sendMultipartTextMessage(to,null, parts, null, null);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, ex.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Arashdn, Any luck. I want same feature(Do not save SMS in set items). Can  you please tell me if you solved this

Comment: @GangadharNimbally , No , I couldn't find any way...

Comment: there in only one way, see my accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25988574/delete-sms-from-android-on-4-4-4-affected-rows-0zero-after-deleted/25989218#25989218